# Scala Extending Parameterized Abstract Class

Tags: oop, scala, inheritance

I'm fairly new to Scala, and am writing an API library and trying to use only vals and immutable objects (where possible). I'm trying to decide on the right way to model the objects. Suppose there are several "Post" objects, which all share some common fields, and each adds its own specific fields:

```
abstract class Post(val id: Int, val name: String, ...)
case class TextPost(val id: Int, val name: String, ..., val text: String) extends Post(id, name, ...)
case class PhotoPost(val id: Int, val name: String, ..., val url: String) extends Post(id, name, ...)
```

This method adds a lot of repetitive declarations and boiler-plate code, especially when dealing with many Post subclasses and shared fields declare in the abstract class. The way I see it, this is caused by the use of vals which can only be initialized by the constructor. Is there a better way to create the relationships detailed here, or must I suffer this for wanting to use only immutable objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the `val` modifiers in the case-class constructors are redundant, the Scala compiler will give them to you already "for free" (it's one of the features of case-classes). If you actually tried to compile that, you will see that an error occurs because of undeclared overriding:

```
abstract class Post(val id: Int, val name: String )
case class TextPost(id: Int, name: String) extends Post(id, name )
case class PhotoPost(id: Int, name: String) extends Post(id, name )

<console>:10: error: overriding value id in class Post of type Int;
 value id needs `override' modifier
           case class PhotoPost(id: Int, name: String) extends Post(id, name )
                                ^
```

I personally recommend to use abstract classes with constructor arguments as little as possible. Scala has traits which do a better job here. Instead of constructor arguments, you declare (abstractly) the fields; then the case classes kick in and due to them making their arguments automatically `vals`, you are done:

```
trait Post { def id: Int; def name: String }
case class TextPost(id: Int, name: String, text: String) extends Post
case class PhotoPost(id: Int, name: String, url: String) extends Post
```

Furthermore, if you add `sealed` to the `trait Post`, you can safely use the subtypes of `Post` in pattern matching without accidentally missing cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In terms of boiler-plate code, this method basically saves me from declaring each parameter in derived classes as a val, but I still must repeat all parameters in each declaration, right? I'm emphasizing this, because I have 8 subclasses and 15 shared fields, and this seems like such a huge DRY case. But I understand from your answer that there is no way around this, right?

Comment: The only other alternative is to _not_ implement the common interface (`Post`). That means you need to _compose_ the type to contain it, but I don't know if that's what you want: `case class Post(id: Int, name: String); case class TextPost(post: Post, text: String)`.

Comment: I don't feel this answer is sufficient since it doesn't answer the boiler plate question...